# Data flow mapping custom join getting error DF-Executor-ColumnNotFound but column exists

Tags: azure-functions, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have an azure mapping data flow that is called from an azure-synapse pipeline.  I need to change one of the joins in the mapping data flow from inner to custom because the correct date isn't being returned and I need to use between, equal, and, or functions for the join.

Here is the current join [current inner join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soPnA.png), I underlined the join between the mgr id's on the inner join.

I started out simple on the custom join, because this is the first time I have used the custom join.  This is first part of my logic for the custom join expression,
[custom join expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdX1d.png), I underlined the search the expression values and I see the value listed.  I have tried typing it in and I have tried clicking on it and it doesn't like it either way.

This is the part of the data flow mapping, where the problem is happening. [join5 managers for results of join4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VeKN.png)

When I get pass this simple part of the join error, my final expression will be
and(equals(Asgnmt_PS_MANAGER_POSITION_ID,mgr_PS_Manager_position_id),or(between(selectemployees@EFF_DT, Mgr_comp_eff_dt,Mgr_comp_eff_end_dt),between(selectemployees@END_EFF_DT,Mgr_comp_eff_dt,Mgr_comp_eff_end_dt)))

Any idea's on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

I tried clicking to add the expression value in and I tried typing them in.  I am starting with a simple version of the join.

Comment: Could you share sample input data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this error for sample datasets. Initially I had column called Time in my `source2`. Again when running the dataflow, the column is removed and it gave error message like `at source 'source1'....unavailable or invalid`.

[image]

Below are some potential fixes for this issue:

- Verify that the input dataset used in the join transformation has the column **mgr_PS_Manager_position_id**. You may achieve this by taking a look at the input dataset's schema in the data flow.
- Check that the join transformation and the custom expression both use the right spelling for the column name.
- Make sure the input dataset used in the join transformation has the correct definition and availability of the column `mgr_PS_Manager_position_id` if it was created through a prior transformation.
- You can give expression like
  `equals(join5@Asgnmt_PS_MANAGER_POSITION_ID,managers@mgr_PS_Manager_position_id)`, so that, `mgr_PS_Manager_position_id` will
- Make sure the file schema of **managers** matches the schema if the input dataset is a file-based dataset.